# Do we have an option to run multiple spiders "independently" at the same time?

Tags: python, scrapy

This was already asked multiple times, but I don't see any solid answer for this. Years ago, this was also asked at: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3216. I currently running 300+ spiders sequentially and dynamically from a django database. I also tried to run the spiders simultaneously using `CrawlerProcess`, but I preferred  to run sequentially  using `CrawlerRunner` based results especially when using `chrome-driver` for highly structured dynamic websites.

I need something to run the each spider in non-blocking process, independently or something like asynchronously? Running hundred or thousand spiders using scrapy common practices (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html.) take enormous amount of time though. Is there any option you can suggest?

Here is my initial code:

```
# Run spiders sequentially
configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():

    for results in match_spiders(Model.objects.all(), settings):
        for spider, url in results:
            yield runner.crawl(spider, url=url)
            print(f'Done running: {spider.__name__}')

    reactor.stop()
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  `CrawlerProcess` is designed specifically to provide the service you request.  I suppose you could use `multiprocessing` to launch multiple spiders, but that's going to run multiple instances of Chrome.  It's going to require a lot of resources.

Comment: @TimRoberts Do you have any example or recommended resources for `multiprocessing` that I can take a look at? that's highly appreciated

Comment: The Python docs:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html , and there are a lot of tutorial websites.  You would want to use a `pool` to keep the number of processes down, but again I don't think this buys you anything not available in `CrawlerProcess`.

Comment: @TimRoberts at least, there's something we can look at if not part of `scrapy`'s scope...ok, cool!